# Mysql results duplicated even though the query does not match

Tags: php, mysql

apologize firstly for my questionable coding in php/mysql however this is all self taught (possibly not best practice)

All my code seems to work , however when the results are written to the page any `$dxcall` that is not in the `$qrzdata` database gets filled with the last result all other data displays fine. I have tried changing the `like $dxcall` to `= $dxcall`. I have also tried combining the fetch arrays too incase my issues was there too. But clearly my code does not know how to handle where there is not data match in the qrzdata database and to move on.

`$frqry` is the main data, all the other mysql_query's be it the `$squares` and `$qrzdata` are matching what comes from `$frqry`. Hope this makes sense !!

Here is my code

```
$frqry = mysql_query("select * from spots where freq between '69900' and '70300' ORDER BY datetime desc limit 30");
While ($r0 = mysql_fetch_array($frqry))
{
$freq = $r0["freq"];
$dxcall = $r0["dxcall"];
$datetime = $r0["datetime"];
$comments = $r0["comments"];
$spotter = $r0["spotter"];
$dt = date('d-m-y H:i ', $datetime);
$qra = $r0["loc"];

$squares = mysql_query("select * from squares where callsign like '$dxcall' limit 1");
while ($r1 = mysql_fetch_array($squares))
{
$qra = $r1["loc"];
}

$qrzdata = mysql_query("select * from qrzdata where callsign = '".$dxcall."' limit 1");
While ($r2 = mysql_fetch_array($qrzdata))
{
$country = $r2["country"];
$firstname = $r2["firstname"];
$city = $r2["city"];
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: What's the point of those nested `while` if you use `LIMIT 1` in your queries?

Answer (score 2):

You need to learn about the power of the [`JOIN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/join.html) ;)

Your whole code could be rewritten in one single query :

*disclaimer: not tested, but you certainly get the idea*

```sql
SELECT * FROM spots
JOIN squares ON (squares.callsign = spots.dxcall) -- this comes in stead of your first inner loop
JOIN qrzdata ON (qrzdata.callsign = spots.dxcall) -- this is your second loop
WHERE freq BETWEEN 69900 AND 70300 -- remove quotes, you are dealing with integers, not strings (hopefully)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to reset your vars!

```
While ($r0 = mysql_fetch_array($frqry))
{
    $qra = '';
    $country = '';
    $firstname = '';
    $city = '';
```

or you will allways get the last value